# Volver un bytes.hex() a su tipo original anterior en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Supongamos que en Python tengo un objeto `b'H\x82m\x8d\xb5wb&J\xea\H\x82m\x8d'`, cuando utilizo la función `.hex()` sobre él, lo convierte a un str hexadecimal: `'48826d8db57762264aea5c48826d8d'` .

**¿Hay alguna forma de volver a mi byte original?**

Es decir, pasar de hexadecimal al byte anterior *(desconozco cómo se llama correctamente este formato.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí, es posible.  Pero no sé como el anterior objeto fue.

De la documentación de Python [Tipos de secuencias binarias — bytes, bytearray y memoryview](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview)

Si fuera un objeto binario, puedes utilizar el método bytes.fromhex()

```
>>>bytes.fromhex('2Ef0 F1f2  ')
b'.\xf0\xf1\xf2'
```

Si fuera un arreglo, puedes utilizar el método bytearray.fromhex()

```
>>>bytearray.fromhex('2Ef0 F1f2  ')
bytearray(b'.\xf0\xf1\xf2')
```